# Creating rounded corners for top half of the buttons in CSS

Tags: css

I would like to make rounded corners only for the top half of buttons.

I know how to make rounded corners for all sides using `border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius`.

But only like to have corners for the top half.

I need some guidance on how to do this in CSS.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick replies.. learnt something new today...

Comment: [example] border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0; Just remember the acronym "TRBL" or the mnemonic "rounded buttons are trouble" for Top(left) Right Bottom(right) Left. Basically moving clockwise.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the following styling rules:

```
border-top-left-radius
border-top-right-radius
```

Note: The `border-radius` rule works without the `-webkit-` bit.

Answer (score 51):

When I want to round specific corners I use code below

```
border-radius: 10px     10px      0           0;
            // top-left top-right bottom-right bottom-left.
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's the pattern I like to use:

**CSS**

```
.round-corners-5px{
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.round-corners-10px{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.unround-top-corners{
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}
.unround-bottom-corners{
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="round-corners-5px unround-bottom-corners" style="background-color: white;"></button>
```

Answer (score 6):

There are specific variants of the border-radius css tag for this:

```
border-top-left-radius:2em; 
border-top-right-radius:2em;
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. Can be reduced to border-radius: 2em 2em 0 0;

Comment: @JGallardo what if the user needs to inherit the border radius for the bottom left/right, can we do `border-radius: 2em 2em inherit inherit`? That's still pretty long, and less readable (for people who can never remember the ordering of all 4 properties).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to round only certain corners, this is the code for it:

```
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
```

The first value is for the top left corner, second for the top right corner, third for the bottom left corner and fourth for the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 3):

If you use sass scss, then you could write it once and reuse it as a simple line of code like this:

In your sass or scss file, define mixin like this:

```
@mixin rounded($amount: "10px",$position: null) {
  @if $position != null {
    @if $position == "top" or $position == "bottom" {
      //top or bottom
      -webkit-border-#{$position}-left-radius: $amount;
      -moz-border-#{$position}-left-radius: $amount;
      border-#{$position}-left-radius: $amount;

      -webkit-border-#{$position}-right-radius: $amount;
      -moz-border-#{$position}-right-radius: $amount;
      border-#{$position}-right-radius: $amount;

    } @else {
      // top-left or top-right or bottom-left or bottom-right
      -webkit-border-#{$position}-radius: $amount;
      -moz-border-#{$position}-radius: $amount;
      border-#{$position}-radius: $amount;      
    }
  } @else {
    // ALL IF EMPTY
    -webkit-border-radius: $amount;
    -moz-border-radius: $amount;
    border-radius: $amount; 
  }

}
```

Then in the scss file you can use mixin like so:

```
  @include rounded(); /*as default 10px on all corners*/
  @include rounded(15px); /*all corners*/ 

  @include rounded(15px, top); /*all top corners*/ 
  @include rounded(15px, bottom); /* all bottom corners*/ 

  @include rounded(15px, top-right); /*this corner only*/ 
  @include rounded(15px, top-left); /*this corner only*/ 
  @include rounded(15px, bottom-right); /*this corner only*/ 
  @include rounded(15px, bottom-left); /*this corner only*/
```

This .scss code will generate this .css code:

```
 /*  as default 10px on all corners */
  -webkit-border-radius: "10px";
  -moz-border-radius: "10px";
  border-radius: "10px";


  /*  all corners  
  */
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;


  /*  all top corners   
  */
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;


  /*  all bottom corners   
  */
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;


  /*  top-right corner only  
  */
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;


  /*  top-left corner only  
  */
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;


  /*  bottom-right corner only  
  */
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;


  /*  bottom-left corner only   
  */
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px; }
```

Comment: To simplify this in SASS you could write it as `@mixin rounded($amount:"10px 10px 10px 10px") {
  -moz-border-radius: $amount;
  -webkit-border-radius: $amount;
  border-radius: $amount;
  -khtml-border-radius: $amount;
}` in which you input all radial amounts as the $amount (top-left top-right bottom-left bottom-right)

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) helps to understand how it works,
 i did this to make left squared and right rounded corners :

```
.btn-circle.btn-lg {
        width: 170px;
        height: 47px;
        padding: 10px 16px;
        font-size: 17px;
        line-height: 1.33;
        /*border-radius: 25px;*/ //use this for both side rounded corner side
        border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px / 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    }
```

[this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/circle-button) guide helped me to make rounded buttons in twitter bootstrap