# Correct way to create rounded corners in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, css

I've just started with **Twitter Bootstrap** and here is one question.

I am creating custom `<header>` block, and I want it's bottom corners to be rounded.

Is there any "correct" way to do this by using predefined classes, or I have to specify it manually like:

```
border-radius: 10px;               // and all that cross-browser trumpery
```

*For now, I'm using `css` styles. Maybe it will be better to use `less` for that issue?*

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483708/creating-rounded-corners-for-top-half-of-the-buttons-in-css/28781315#28781315) recently i tried left squared right rounded , hope helps someone

Comment: I'm assuming that by 'predefined classes', you just want to add a class to your `<header>` and give it rounded corners, and generally make it look bootstrappy. Here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29383075/1450294

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I guess it is what you are looking for: http://blogsh.de/tag/bootstrap-less/

```
@import 'bootstrap.less';
div.my-class {
    .border-radius( 5px );
}
```

You can use it because there is a mixin:

```
.border-radius(@radius: 5px) {
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
     -moz-border-radius: @radius;
          border-radius: @radius;
}
```

For Bootstrap 3, there are 4 mixins you can use...

```
.border-top-radius(@radius);
.border-right-radius(@radius);
.border-bottom-radius(@radius);
.border-left-radius(@radius);
```

or you can make your own mixin using the top 4 to do it in one shot.

```
.border-radius(@radius){
    .border-top-radius(@radius);
    .border-right-radius(@radius);
    .border-bottom-radius(@radius);
    .border-left-radius(@radius);
}
```

Comment: So, I have to use `less` for that and it's impossible with `bootstrap.css`?

Comment: Bootstrap3 does not have such a mixin.

Comment: The question asked for 'predefined classes'—you're creating classes here. See this answer for the predefined classes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29383075/1450294

Comment: Each of the Bootstrap 3 shortcut mixins (.border-top-radius, .border-right-radius, etc.) round 2 corners, so you can round all 4 via a .border-radius mixin using only left and right, or top and bottom.  You can also round 3 corners via the appropriate combination, e.g. top and left will round bottom-left, top-left, and top-right.

Comment: Chrome gives a malware warning for that blogsh.de site

Answer (score 94):

`<div class="img-rounded">` will give you rounded corners.

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits No. It works just fine on divs too. I don't like using it because it's a bit confusing, but it does work.

Comment: If it's not an image, it's likely a panel, and there's a syntactically correct class for that, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29383075/1450294

Answer (score 17):

Bootstrap is just a big, useful, yet simple **CSS file** - not a framework or anything you can't override. I say this because I've noticed many developers got stick with BS classes and became lazy "I-can't-write-CSS-code-anymore" coders [this not being your case of course!].

If it features something you need, go with Bootstrap classes - if not, go write your additional code in good ol' `style.css`.

To have best of both worlds, you may write your own declarations in LESS and recompile the whole thing upon your needs, minimizing server request as a bonus.

Comment: Yes, sure. :) Just don't want to invent bicycle.

Comment: you mean re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: Inventing the bicycle would be awesome.

Comment: Is this bike-shedding about bike wheel analogies? #humour

Comment: I think the concern is what happens when the bicycle gets pimped up—he wants his widget to still fit. (I mean this in all seriousness, even though it may sound a bit sus. ) The problem with directly manipulating CSS is that it might not suit the overall theme, especially if the theme changes, e.g. with a plug-in or Bootstrap update. I would argue that using an appropriate CSS class is no more 'lazy' than using an appropriate constant in code, instead of typing a magic number.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, but you never know when you will need to add or change a little bit of something to that wheel, so knowledge of the wheel components and how they work are always useful.

Answer (score 10):

As per bootstrap 3.0 documentation. there is no rounded corners  **class** or **id** for div *tag*.

you can use circle behavior for image  by using

```
<img class="img-circle">
```

or just use custom `border-radius` css3 property in css

for only bottom rounded coner use following

```
border-bottom-left-radius:25%; // i use percentage  u can use pix.
border-bottom-right-radius:25%;// i use percentage  u can use pix.
```

if you want **responsive** circular div then [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/QmPhb/10/)

referred from [Responsive CSS Circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945891/responsive-css-circles)

Answer (score 10):

What you want is a Bootstrap [panel](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-basic). Just add the `panel` class, and your header will look uniform. You can also add classes `panel panel-info`, `panel panel-success`, etc. It works for pretty much any block element, and should work with `<header>`, but I expect it would be used mostly with `<div>`s.

Answer (score 8):

Without less, ans simply for a given div :

In a css :

```
.footer {
background-color: #ab0000;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

In  html :

```
 <div class="footer">
        <p>blablabla</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

#### With bootstrap4 you can easily do it like this :-

```
class="rounded"
```

or

```
class="rounded-circle"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Bootstrap Sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass), here's another way that avoids having to add extra classes to your element markup:

```
@import "bootstrap/mixins/_border-radius";
@import "bootstrap/_variables";

.your-class {
  $r: $border-radius-base; // or $border-radius-large, $border-radius-small, ...
  @include border-top-radius($r);
  @include border-bottom-radius($r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4, the correct way to border your elements is to name them as follows in the class list of your elements:

```
For a slight rounding effect on all corners; class="rounded"
For a slight rounding on the left; class="rounded-left"
For a slight rounding on the top; class="rounded-top"
For a slight rounding on the right; class="rounded-right"
For a slight rounding on the bottom; class="rounded-bottom" 
For a circle rounding, i.e. your element is made circular; class="rounded-circle"
And to remove rounding effects; class="rounded-0"
```

To use Bootstrap 4 css files, you can simply use the CDN, and use the following link in the  of your HTML file:

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This will provided you with the basics of Bootstrap 4. However if you would like to use the majority of Bootstrap 4 components, including tooltips, popovers, and dropdowns, then you are best to use the following code instead:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can install Bootstrap using NPM, or Bower, and link to the files there.

*Note that the bottom  tag of the three is the same as the first  tag in the first link path.

A full working example, could be :

```
<img src="path/to/my/image/image.jpg" width="150" height="150" class="rounded-circle mx-auto">
```

In the above example, the image is centered by using the Bootstrap auto margin on left and right.