# Responsive CSS Circles

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-shapes

### Goal:

**Responsive CSS circles that:**

1. Scale with equal radius.
2. Radius can be calculated by percent.
3. Radius can be controlled by media queries.

---

*If solution is **javascript**, I still need to emulate media query triggers. I dont 'need' media queries but I do want the ability to control the radius by percentage at certain widths:*

```
@media (max-width : 320px) 
{
    .x2{padding: 50%;}
}

@media (min-width : 321px) and (max-width : 800px)
{
    .x2{padding: 25%;}
}

@media (min-width: 801px)
{
    .x2{padding: 12.5%;}
}
```

**Here is what I have so far:**

http://jsfiddle.net/QmPhb/

```
<div class="x1">
    <div class="x2">
        lol dude      
    </div>
    <div class="x2"></div>
    <div class="x2"></div>
    <div class="x2"></div>
</div>

.x1
{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

.x2
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding: 12.5%;          //Currently being used to control radius.
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    background:#eee;
    text-align:center;
}
```

### Problems:

**In this solution, when content is added to a circle:**

- The shape contorts when scaled past it's available padding.
- Increases the size of the radius.

---

### Update:

I've built a working solution for this here: 
[Responsive CSS Circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945891/responsive-css-circles/14013200#14013200)

Comment: The problems you listed are caused by `width: auto; height: auto;`. Are fixed dimensions acceptable? Maybe with relative units?

Comment: It's going to be hard to have it work with CSS only, being that  the width and height need to be the same, and since it's responsive, you won't be able to tell.

Comment: @bfavaretto The need is really so that the radius or diameter could be calculated by percent similar to the example.

Comment: @coopersita I am not against using javascript, but we still need to keep media query triggers in mind.

Comment: @DanKanze `@media` queries are not needed in your case.

Comment: How about wrapping the content in an absolutely positioned element? http://jsfiddle.net/QmPhb/4/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/QmPhb/5/) using fixed dimensions.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Please refer to updates to see what I mean.

Comment: @DanKanze Dude, check it out using `@media` queries: http://jsfiddle.net/QmPhb/10/embedded/result/ Do you still need them? Seriously? It actually craps up everything instead of helping us!

Comment: @PraveenKumar I dont 'need' them haha but I do want the ability to control the radius by percentage at certain widths. Even if the solution uses javascript.

Comment: Ah! I still don't understand your exact use case! `:P` Would you mind explaining in a detailed way again? Sorry! `:(`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/WTWrB/

**The DIV structure:**

*We use `overflow:hidden` in `.x2` for spill off background colors in `.x3`
   of child elements.*

*Notice the content starts inside of `.x3`*

```
<div class="x0">
    <div class="x1">
        <div class="x2">
            <div class="x3">
                <!-- BEG Content -->
                <div class="x4">
                    dude
                </div>
                <div class="x6">
                    <div class="x7">
                        dude
                    </div>
                    <div class="x8">
                        dude
                    </div>
                </div>                
                <div class="x5">
                    dude
                </div>
                <!-- END Content -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="x2"></div>
        <div class="x2"></div>
        <div class="x2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
@media (max-width: 320px)
{
    .x2 {padding: 50%;}
}

@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 800px)
{
    .x2 {padding: 25%;}
}

@media (min-width: 801px)
{
    .x1 {width:800px}
    .x2 {padding: 12.5%;}
}
.x0 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.x1 {
    margin:0px auto;
}
.x2 {
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    background:#eee;
}
.x3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    font-size: 100%;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
/* BEG Content */
.x3 div{float:left;}
.x4,.x5,.x6 {
    width:100%;
}
.x7,.x8 {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
.x4,.x5,.x7,.x8 {
    text-align:center;
}
.x4 {
    background-color:blue;
    height:20%;
}
.x5 {
    background-color:yellow;
    height:20%;
}
.x6 {
    height:60%;
}
.x7 {
    background-color:green;
}
.x8 {
    background-color:orange;
}
/* END Content */
```

[image: Responsive CSS Circles]

Answer (score 14):

You don't need `@media` queries for this. This is my try, pure CSS:

```
.x1 {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.x1 .x2 {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding: 12.5%;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    background:#eee;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}
.x1 .x2 span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 48%;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    font-size: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}​
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QmPhb/10/)

[**Full Screen**](http://jsfiddle.net/QmPhb/10/embedded/result/)

Comment: This certainly addresses the overflow problem. I guess I would expect the Circles to stack @ 25% padding (2 rows) and 50% padding (4 rows) though. Is that possible with this solution?

Comment: Yeah, for that to be possible, we need to use media queries then! :)

Comment: Hopefully this gives better context for the kind of flexibility I need. http://jsfiddle.net/tgXKK/

Comment: @DanKanze Nothing gets rendered inside! `:O` Gimme a few mins will finish it soon. `:)`

Comment: I'm curious have you come up with anything yet?

Comment: ohhh very cool you should add to that code / link to your post ;)

Comment: The un-prefixed CSS should *follow* the vendor-prefixed versions (so the 'final' version is used to override the vendor-prefixed 'draft' versions). Also you left out `o-border-radius` (which is okay since, I think, Opera -as well as Webkit and Mozilla- can just use the regular `border-radius` property).

Comment: I made several revisions to this code and minified it the best I could. There were a couple properties I added to allow for more flexibility in child content container elements. See edits above.

Comment: You keep getting thumbed up but I dont think they realize I need improvments to the exhisting solution lol... Want to work for the bounty =) ?

Comment: @DanKanze Just saw that got those upvotes. Am not well (fever for 3 days), okay, deal... Will work. Gimme time till tomorrow evening (say 20 hours from now) may be? Will get some good solution!

Comment: also chrome seems to hate full width blocks and doesn thide overflow. http://jsfiddle.net/QmPhb/17/

Comment: Actually I tested with Chrome only!

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to hide overflow.

Comment: @DanKanze What's with the bounty? What happened to you?

Comment: Your solution really only solved half the problem. even though it received a lot of attention does not mean when people try to use this outside the jsfiddle it will actually be portable. I asked you several times to revise your answer to accommodate the bounty and you never modified.

Comment: Fine okay. :) No issues. As I said you, I wasn't well.

Comment: The part you solved was very helpful and did overcame a difficult piece. This was the ability to fix content within circle divs without affecting the radius. When this question becomes unlocked we are still looking for a way to solve chrome overflow problem and a way (if possible) to eliminate helper class that encapsulates circle divs.

Comment: Why was it **locked** at the first place? Sorry, I was not active for a few days and saw that the question had issues this way. That's why asking you. You lost your **50** bounty points na!!! I was concerned with that issue!

Answer (score 7):

### Shorter Code

This solution reduces your code size but keeps the functionality in place. I've kept the original `.x#`, eliminating the `.x0`, `.x3`, and `.x6` that were not needed. So in a final solution, you would probably renumber (but I wanted you to see what was eliminated).

Any of your pieces "splitting" the circle that require a different `top` or `left` setting will need to have a selector that meets or exceeds the `.x2 > div` selector to override, hence why I have `.x2 > .x7` etc. for some of my selectors.

(As noted in the comments below, [Chrome has bug issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera) with the original technique the OP had posted at the time of the bounty starting. This does not solve those, so view the following in another browser.)

### [Here's the modified fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/WTWrB/9/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="x1">
        <div class="x2">
                <!-- BEG Content -->
                <div class="x4">
                    dude
                </div>
                <div class="x7">
                    dude
                </div>
                <div class="x8">
                    dude
                </div>
                <div class="x5">
                    dude
                </div>
                <!-- END Content -->
        </div>
        <div class="x2"></div>
        <div class="x2"></div>
        <div class="x2"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.x1 {
    margin:0px auto;
}
.x2 {
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    background:#eee;
}

/* BEG Content */
.x2 > div {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.x4,.x5 {
    width:100%;
    height: 20%;
}
.x2 > .x7, .x2 > .x8 {
    width:50%;
    height: 60%;
    top: 20%;
}
.x4 {
    background-color:blue;
}
.x2 > .x5 {
    background-color:yellow;
    top: 80%;
}

.x7 {
    background-color:green;
}
.x2 > .x8 {
    background-color:orange;
    left: 50%;
}
/* END Content */
@media (max-width: 320px)
{
    .x2 {padding: 50%;}
}

@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 800px)
{
    .x2 {padding: 25%;}
}

@media (min-width: 801px)
{
    .x1 {width:800px}
    .x2 {padding: 12.5%;}
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on comments, it appears the OP desired something more like **[the control this fiddle offers](http://jsfiddle.net/WTWrB/23/)** (not functional in Chrome; the OP has not at the time of this edit replied for me to know if that is the type of functionality desired or not).

Comment: Ahh yea I didnt say that correctly. `.x2` divs are stacking fine. You have also eliminated `.x3`...which is great. What I meant is that using overrides to apply styles in `.x2` child elements is undesirable.

Comment: @DanKanze--how much flexibility versus standardization do you want in the "layouts" inside these circles? Are they all the same? Each one different? Your goal is "improved" and "smaller". Well, I got the code smaller, but what is "improved"? That depends a lot on what functionality you want.

Comment: From a developer point of view an **ideal** solution would be one that easy to build (rolling out styles inside of `.x2` blocks without overrides) and optimizes arbitrary code (trim fat like `.x3` only used as a helper class to accomadate the build flexibility in `.x2`). An **ideal** solution would be a single class that enabled a developer too use `.x2` like a `block` as well as contain them.

Comment: @DanKanze--have you looked at your original fiddle solution in Chrome? It fails to hide the overflow because of the bug noted in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera).

Comment: @DanKanze--[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WTWrB/23/) (look at in Firefox or IE9+, see comment above) that controls things by a `layout` class on the content wrapper. Is that more what you are talking about? It is certainly not necessarily "smaller" in size, but the layout class can be coded by the developer and the class applied by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I know this solution differs quite a bit from what has been suggested here but I still thought it would be worth putting it up.

I used an image as a mask to create the circle and took advantage of the fact that when padding is specified as a percentage it is calculated based on the width of its parent element rather than the height. This enabled me to create a perfect square.

Demonstration of circles proportionally resizing [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/wwtHR/)

HTML code

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="circle" src="circleImage.png">
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    background-color: #bbb;

}

.circle { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .container { width: 100%; padding-bottom: 100%; }
}

@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    .container { width: 50%; padding-bottom: 50%; }
}

@media (min-width: 801px) {
    .container { width: 25%; padding-bottom: 25%; }
}
```

Demonstration of the above circles sub-divided into sections as per your question [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/YbMng/)

Comment: how about the box-shadow property with this solution?