# Bootstrap 3 buttons - change border radius

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've searched around but whatever I try, I can't make my buttons have a border radius of zero globally. This doesn't work, can anyone help? thanks!

```
.btn btn-default{
    border-radius: 0px!important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px!important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px!important;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to create rounded corners in Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084121/correct-way-to-create-rounded-corners-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: Your class selector is missing a `.` before `btn-default`.

Answer (score 6):

```
 border-radius: 24px!important;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that for me, I simply had to remove `type=button` as I had originally copy/pasted the bootstrap button from Bootstrap tutorials

I.E.

```
<a type="button" class="custom-css btn btn-primary btn-lg">foobar</a>
```

becomes

```
<a class="custom-css btn btn-primary btn-lg">foobar</a>
```