# Make a rounded bootstrap container or image more 'rounded' i.e. increase roundedness?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I followed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21056695/5783745) to make the corners of each image in a grid 'rounded', it it worked as expected (see screenshot below)

But I would prefer the rounded corners to be a little more pronounced, as indicated roughly with the green line in the screenshot. How can this be done?

[image]

The current code I'm using is

```
<img class="rounded" src="img.png">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4** has a `rounded-lg` class which sets `border-radius: .3rem`.

If you want more radius than that override it with your own CSS class...

```
.rounded-xl {
   border-radius: .5rem;
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/udzCt1qKQV)

Bootstrap 5 has [3 numeric sizes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/borders/#sizes).